# How to arrange the components of the ritualistic platter?

Tags: puja

What is the right way to arrange the components of the ritualistic platter?

Answer (score 2):

**Arrangement based on cosmic elements**

> Before commencing the actual ritualistic worship (pūjā), it is
>   important to arrange the tools and other components used in the
>   ritualistic worship in a spiritually beneficial manner. From the
>   viewpoint of the science of spirituality it is appropriate to arrange
>   them based on the level of the five cosmic elements. The cosmic
>   elements are Absolute Earth (Pruthvi), Absolute Water (Āpa), Absolute
>   Fire (Tēj), Absolute Wind (Vāyu) and Absolute Ether (Ākāsh). The
>   reason for an arrangement based on the cosmic elements is that such an
>   arrangement balances and coordinates the five cosmic elements that are
>   active in the universe. This helps the embodied soul (worshipper) to
>   derive maximum benefit from the manifest (saguṇ) and unmanifest
>   (nirguṇ) frequencies emitted by the Deity being ritualistically
>   worshipped.
>
> **Arranging the components of the ritualistic worship platter**
>
> The arrangement of the components of the ritualistic platter is as
>   seen in the above image. It is explained in the two-dimensional
>   context of the relative position of the Deity being ritualistically
>   worshipped and the worshipper. Thus, ‘at the forefront’ refers to the
>   part of the platter positioned close to the image or idol of the Deity
>   being worshipped, and ‘lower end of the platter’ refers to the part of
>   the platter positioned close to the worshipper.

[Source](http://www.forumforhinduawakening.org/living/arranging-ritualistic-platter)

- ‘In the ritualistic platter turmeric and vermilion is to be placed to
  the right of the embodied soul and bukka, gulal and shendur to the
  left.
- The perfume bottle, fragrant paste (usually sandalwood paste),
  flowers, durva and leaves (patri) are to be placed at the forefront
  in the platter. The subtle frequencies of the deities are activated
  by the fragrance particles in the perfume, sandalwood paste, flowers
  and also by the colour particles in the durva and leaves.
- The betel leaves, betel nut and the money to be offered in the ritual
  of offering money (dakshina) are to be placed at the lower end of the
  platter because they are an effective medium of transmission of
  frequencies of the deities.
- In the center, the all encompassing unbroken rice grains are to be
  placed. As the unbroken rice grains become the central portion of the
  platter, the frequencies of the five superior deities namely, Shri
  Shiva, Shri Durga, Shri Shriram, Shri Shrikrushna and Shri Ganapati
  are attracted to them. They are then transmitted as per the
  requirement to the other components, e.g. vermilion, turmeric, etc.
  placed around them in a circular manner.’